# Doubletap on textfield

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

In my mobile app, I have a FormPanel with a fieldset with textfields that could have been filled from some desktop application, by a skilled secretary with well beyond 300 keystrokes per minute.

So I want to provide the possibility to open a bigger field on doubletap onto the textfield, but I can't get the listener to work.

As of now, my code looks like this:

```
config:{
    ...
    listeners : [{
        fn:'onClearIconTap',
        event:'clearicontap',
        delegate:'textfield'
    },{
        fn:'onItemDblTap',//'onTextFieldDblTap',
        event:'itemdoubletap',//'doubletap'
        //delegate:'fieldset'//'textfield'
    }]
```

The clearIconTap event is fired, but I can't get the doubletap to work.

How can I listen to that event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is expected behaviour, if you check `Ext.field.Text` documentation the `doubletap` event is not exposed by that component. That is a design choice for performance reason, they chose to listen to and expose only the events they considered relevant for each component.

That said, you can listen to events directly on the Ext.dom.Element associated to that component:

Try this:

```
{
    fn:'onItemDblTap',
    event:'doubletap',
    element: 'element'
}
```